# VB.Net program that stores data to a webserver

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I wanted to used standard TCP/IP connection using MYSQLconnection. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not this is the best way depends on your environment.  For many cases, this would not be the correct way to go about things, because the person running the client program would have direct access to your database. You would also be required to open your firewall to allow anybody running your application to have access to the database.  Not only security problems, but if you wanted to change the queries being run to perform a particular action, then you would have to ensure that everyone updated their client program.  An alternative way of doing something like this that may work better, would be to create a web server (XML, SOAP, JSON, etc.) that your VB.Net program called to complete various actions.  That way the VB.Net program would not have to connect to the database directly, which would allow both for increased security, as well as allow you to change things on the server side such as table structure without the VB.Net program being aware.